# Deadlock When Updating different PK rows

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-integration, deadlock

I have a problem with my SPring Integration application.

In one point of the code, the apllication throws this error:
ORA-00060 - DEADLOCK DETECTED

I see this in the trace:

```
    Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-00024912-00000000        58     395    SX   SSX       61     441    SX   SSX
TM-00024912-00000000        61     441    SX   SSX       58     395    SX   SSX

session 395: DID 0001-003A-000458EF session 441: DID 0001-003D-0002C56C 
session 441: DID 0001-003D-0002C56C session 395: DID 0001-003A-000458EF 

Rows waited on:
  Session 395: no row
  Session 441: no row
```

I am sure that the query update two differents rows
How is it possible that a deadlock occurs in different PK rows?

Comment: Do you have a supporting index on the **foriegn key**? Also, please read https://lalitkumarb.com/2014/02/25/understanding-oracle-deadlock/

Comment: I have four foreigns keys that reference the table, but i cant disable three of this bacause is used for partitioning (The BBDD is partitioned by foreign key).

Comment: You should share more info for Java developers if you'd like to have more help...

Comment: The problem start after PARTITIONING the table. Can partitioning cause deadlocks?

Comment: Are you using triggers on this table ?

Comment: You need to describe the table, list the indexes and PK/FK constrainted columns, and list which DML is being performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks all the people for the answers.

The problem was that tablas are partitioned by foreign key reference , and the FK are not indexed , causing deadlocks by Oracle that blocks all the child table.

I have created all the indexes for the foreign keys and the problem is solved.